# How does Stream.reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator) initialized?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

The following code works perfectly without the need to initialize the `reduce` operation.

```
int sum=Stream.of(2,3).reduce((Integer a,Integer b)->a+b).get(); // sum = 5
int sum=Stream.of(2,3).reduce((Integer a,Integer b)->a*b).get(); // sum = 6
```

How does it know that the first accumulator is a `+` so that it should initialize to a new sum = 0, and the second accumulator is a `*` so that it should initialize to a new sum = 1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1-argument `reduce` doesn't start with an identity value (0 or 1).  It only operates on the values in your stream.  If you look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), it even shows the equivalent code:

```
 boolean foundAny = false;
 T result = null;
 for (T element : this stream) {
     if (!foundAny) {
         foundAny = true;
         result = element;
     }
     else
         result = accumulator.apply(result, element);
 }
 return foundAny ? Optional.of(result) : Optional.empty();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is its API specification:

```
Optional<T> java.util.stream.Stream.reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
```

Which returns: an Optional describing the result of the reduction

As per its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), the equivalent code is:

```
boolean foundAny = false;
T result = null;
for (T element : this stream) {
    if (!foundAny) {
        foundAny = true;
        result = element;
    }
    else
        result = accumulator.apply(result, element);
}
return foundAny ? Optional.of(result) : Optional.empty();
```

Three cases:

1. No element in the stream: return Optional.empty()
2. One element: just return the element without applying the accumulator at all.
3. Two or more elements: apply the accumulator to all of them and return the result.

More examples of this reduce method:

```
// Example 1: No element
Integer[] num = {};
Optional<Integer> result = Arrays.stream(num).reduce((Integer a, Integer b) -> a + b);
System.out.println("Result: " + result.isPresent()); // Result: false

result = Arrays.stream(num).reduce((Integer a, Integer b) -> a * b);
System.out.println("Result: " + result.isPresent()); // Result: false

// Example 2: one element   
int sum = Stream.of(2).reduce((Integer a, Integer b) -> a + b).get();
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum); // Sum: 2

int product = Stream.of(2).reduce((Integer a, Integer b) -> a * b).get();
System.out.println("Product: " + product); // Product: 2

// Example 3: two elements
sum = Stream.of(2, 3).reduce((Integer a, Integer b) -> a + b).get();
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum); // Sum: 5

product = Stream.of(2, 3).reduce((Integer a, Integer b) -> a * b).get();
System.out.println("Product: " + product); // Product: 6
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as your stream has one or more elements, you don't need an identity value. The first reduction returns `2+3`, which is equivalent to `0+2+3`. The second returns `2*3`, which is equivalent to `1*2*3`.